# Shell script adding float and integer

Tags: bash, shell

I can't seem to debug the error in the computation of

```
case $code in
    ${menuCode[0]} )
        CBcost=$(echo "${menuItemsCost[0]} * $quantity" |bc) 
        sumOfCheeseBurgers=$(echo "$sumOfCheeseBurgers + $CBcost" |bc) 
    ;;
```

I need to be able to add all the sum of Burgers and store it to `sumOfBurgers` everytime the user enters Y for another transaction. However, I keep getting a `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`. How do I properly express `sumOfBurgers=sumOfBurgers + CBcost?`

```
declare -a menuItems=( 'Cheese Burger' 'Ham Burger' 'Spaghetti' 'Fried  Chicken' 'Softdrinks' )
declare -a menuItemsCost=( 25.00 20.00 24.00 30.00 15.00 )
declare -a menuCode=( CB HB SP FC SD )

clear

printf "MENU\n"
printf "=================================\n"
printf "CODE\tDESCRIPTION\t PRICE\t|\n"
echo   "================================="
printf "${menuCode[0]}  |\t${menuItems[0]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[0]} |\n"
printf "${menuCode[1]}  |\t${menuItems[1]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[1]} |\n"
printf "${menuCode[2]}  |\t${menuItems[2]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[2]} |\n"
printf "${menuCode[3]}  |\t${menuItems[3]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[3]} |\n"
printf "${menuCode[4]}  |\t${menuItems[4]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[4]} |\n"
printf "=================================\n"

choice="Y"
while [ $choice == "Y" ] 
    do
    printf "What's your order please? \n[Enter Code]: "
    read code
        while [ "$code" != "CB" ] && [ "$code" != "HB" ] && [ "$code" != "SP" ] && 
                [ "$code" != "FC" ] && [ "$code" != "SD" ]   
            do 
                printf "Please enter a valid ORDER code. \n[Enter Code]: " 
                    read code
                    code=$code 
        done

printf "Enter Quantity: "
    read quantity
printf "Do another transaction [Y/N]?: "
    read choice

case $code in
     ${menuCode[0]} )
        CBcost=$(echo "${menuItemsCost[0]} * $quantity" |bc) 
        sumOfCheeseBurgers=$(echo "$sumOfCheeseBurgers + $CBcost" |bc) 
    ;;
esac

done

printf "$sumOfCheeseBurgers\n"
```

Comment: Btw, for correct useage of printf see: `help printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise `sumOfCheeseBurgers` before you use it here, otherwise it is an empty string which causes the syntax error from `bc`:

```
sumOfCheeseBurgers=$(echo "$sumOfCheeseBurgers + $CBcost" |bc)
```

Add the following line before the `while` loop:

```
sumOfCheeseBurgers=0
```

Or alternatively, as pointed out in the comments (thanks), you can use this syntax to assign a default value:

```
sumOfCheeseBurgers=$(echo "${sumOfCheeseBurgers-0} + $CBcost" |bc)
```

If you run your script like `bash -x script.sh`, you can see this error more clearly:

```
++ echo ' + 50.00'
++ bc
```

As you can see, the string being passed to `bc` is missing a value before the `+`.

As an aside, you should be using format specifiers with `printf`. For example:

```
printf "${menuCode[0]}  |\t${menuItems[0]}\t| ${menuItemsCost[0]} |\n"
```

should be something like this:

```
printf '%s  |\t%s\t| %s |\n' "${menuCode[0]}" "${menuItems[0]}" "${menuItemsCost[0]}"
```

This is the correct way to use `printf` as it prevents characters within your variables from being interpreted as escape characters (for example, newlines or tab characters).

Comment: ... or use `${SumOfCheeseBurgers-0}` in the `echo`.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I appreciate the tips and the solution you provided. I've finished the program last night and got everything working fine. Some of the syntax in Shell is a bit different. I'll take note of the things I missed. Thanks again.